# Trying to make a Bookmarklet to set a cookie every 6 seconds

Tags: javascript, cookies, bookmarklet

I am not experienced Javascript but I am trying to make a bookmarklet that will run document.cookie (with some arguments) every 6 seconds. I can get the bookmarklet to to the cookie but I cannot figure out how to make a loop. I tried googling how to make a loop and putting it into a javascript to bookmarklet generator but that didn't work. **Can someone please give me the Bookmarklet code (like javascript:blablabla) with something like  for every 6 seconds?** Thank you so much for reading this

Edit: **Also the bookmarklet goes to a different page with the new cookie data but never goes back to the original page, can you guys tell me how to set a cookie without it going to another page?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setInterval();`, it wil execute given function every x milliseconds [W3 schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp).

Comment: Ok thank you works, amazingly! even the function stopped changing the webpage!